# How do I get cookies in System.Web.Http.ApiController?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

This is the only documentation my poor skills were able to dig up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies

But that does not work with `System.Web.Http.ApiController` as `'HttpRequestHeaders' does not contain a definition for 'GetCookies'`

I am sure it is simple, but documentation is either hard to search for or I jsut can't find it - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use cookie in Web API like this

```
var cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("Username");
```

Did you include `using System.Net.Http;`